# How to work with the CABasicAnimations

Tags: iphone

I am very new to the Animations, I need a CABasicAnimation that how to implement for an image to move it to bottom left to upper right. I tried with different examples but I am not succeeded. Alos I not using a Interface Builder I am using a viewcontroller to implement this. Please help  me.

Thanks in Advance,
Sekhar.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0,460)]; //Start position
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(320,0)]; //End Position
anim.duration = 1.0;

[vourImageView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"MoveToUpperRight"];
```

Coded in browser, no guarantee for syntax.

See [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) Chapter Explicit Animations